# Failure reading parquet files

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Azure ML fails to read tabular data set from parquet files, many parquet files.

Creating datasets

```
from azureml.data.datapath import DataPath
datastore_path = [DataPath(datastore, 'churn')]
tabular_dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_parquet_files(path=datastore_path)
```

Comment: Can you please add more details about the size of the parquet files.

Comment: can you provide more info? what is the stacktrace/error message? how many files? how   many directories? what is the average file size?

Comment: Thank you! Each parquet file of size 10GB.

Comment: having a similar issue, but the problem is reading in columns with types that azureml doesn't support https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72650445/azureml-tabulardatasetfactory-from-parquet-files-error-handling-column-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extensions: *.parquet:

```
from azureml.data.datapath import DataPath
datastore_path = [DataPath(datastore, 'churn/*.parquet')]
tabular_dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_parquet_files(path=datastore_path)
```

Other ways to not read all data into memory at once would be to use `skip()` and `take()` on the TabularDataset to only request portions of source data at a time.
Or to mount the Parquet files as a FileDataset and then construct separate TabularDataset for subsets of the files in your training script.

Here’s a sample notebook for your reference: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/parallel-run/tabular-dataset-inference-iris.ipynb